# Retrieve facebook user photo if the user has connected to facebook in some other tab

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Basically I would like to get the users profile picture if the user is logged in to facebook on some other tab in the browser instance. I can see if a the current user is logged in to facebook by doing this:

```
    <script>
    function logged() {
        alert('logged');
    }
    function notlogged() {
        alert('not logged');
    }
    </script>
    <script src="http://www.facebook.com/ajax/composer/attachment/question/question.php" onload="logged()" onerror="notlogged()"></script>
```

I would like a silent way to retrieve the users image if he is logged and that's all.

Comment: The only way for you to know _any_ personal information of a Facebook user is if you create an app and have them log in to that app first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Thank god for that.

Also, your script doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The only instance that can talk to each other is your own tab with same origin or tabs/window created using window.open. Iframes is also a solution

They can talk to each other with postMessage or storage events

so if your site (foo.com) is waiting for some other person to login to facebook or via another domain. eg my site (bar.com) or facebook itself

facebook or bar.com needs to tell you via postmessage that someone has logged in. And needer of them is going to tell you that.